# Testlink cant load template

Tags: php, html, smarty3, testlink, smarty-plugins

I am having a Problem with Testlink. I recently installed the Version 2.0.0 () of Testlink and the Program is running well except for when I want to execute a testcase. When I am in the Testcase Execution Menu and I click on the testcase I only get an empty page. This is caused by the following Error the Programm throws:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:execute/include/inc_exec_img_controls.tpl' in 'execute/include/exec_show_tc_exec.inc.tpl' <-- \n  thrown in /var/www/html/testlink/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 195, referer: `http://localhost/testlink/lib/execute/execNavigator.php?setting_testplan=5&tproject_id=1&tplan_id=5`

Has this ever appeared to anyone else? Does someone have an Idea how to solve this?